# difference between Set = new HashSet and HashSet = new HashSet java

Tags: java, set, hashset

What is the difference between the 2 calls:

```
Set<Record> instances = new HashSet<Record>();  -  on one hand 
HashSet<Record> instances = new HashSet<Record>();  - on other hand
```

Comment: The first line can have the implementation of Set changes easily.

Comment: Set is an interface, HashSet a class

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you can reassign `instances` to an instance of any subtype of `Set<Record>`.  In the second case, you can reassign `instances` only to an instance of a subtype of `HashSet<Record>`.

Comment: When you're answering these kinds of questions, consider the level of expertise of the OP.  If he's struggling over interfaces vs. concrete classes, it's unlikely he's going to know what you mean by "subtype."

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` implements the interface `Set`. Both statements store the HashSet in the variable instances (there is no difference, both statements store the same data).

The first statements however stores the `HashSet` in a `Set`. This has some advantages, for example you could change `HashSet` to `TreeSet` without changing your other code.

Comment: Technically, `Set` is an interface that `HashSet` implements.

Comment: Ups, changed my answer. Thought it was a superclass instead of an interface.

Comment: When you're answering these kinds of questions, consider the level of expertise of the OP.  If he's struggling over interfaces vs. concrete classes, it's unlikely he's going to know what you mean by "upcast."

Comment: @RobertHarvey I am trying, but it's hard to explain such difficult things on a low level of expertise.